# Converting matrix inconsistent shape of np.array to torch.tensor?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

For example, I have an np array containing elements with np. array

```
 (5, 10)
(10, 10)
(32, 10)
(2, 10)
(48, 10)
(72, 10)
(42, 10)
```

how can I convert this kind of array into torch.tensor?

TypeError: can't convert np.ndarray of type numpy.object_. The only supported types are: `float64, float32, float16, int64, int32, int16, int8, and uint8.`

Comment: What is the code that produces the error?

Comment: What's the `shape`?  `dtype` is object.  What does `np.stack(arr)` produce?  shape, dtype?